# jump to the center of the page horizontally in javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll

There are tons of posts about jump to the top of the page in javascript but this question is different in the aspect that I am looking for a function to jump to the centre of the page horizontally if a user scrolls enough horizontally.

Here is my code but it does not work properly and works absolutely wrong on at least an android phone:

```
  function scrollFunction(id) {
        if (Math.abs($(window).width()/2 - document.documentElement.scrollLeft -document.documentElement.scrollWidth/2) > 50) {
            document.getElementById("myBtnBotton").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("myBtnBotton").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, I would add an invisible div. Style this div so it will always be in the center of the page horizontally. Jump to this invisibe div when scrolling more than x times.

Comment: Thanks @Wimanicesir. can you provide an example of that in an answer?

Comment: Your existing code looks like it tries to respond to scrolling by displaying a button. Does "it works absolutely wrong" mean it displays a button instead of "jumping to the centre"?

Comment: @Cat thanks. I print the output to the console and the console shows a value around 2k that is far away from zero .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to detect when u user is halfway on the scrollbar BUT horizontally.

```js
$('#button').hide();

// Event on scroll
$(window).on('scroll',function(e){
  // Get scrolled value
  var value = $('html').scrollLeft();
  
  // Calculated max scroll left
  var maxScrollLeft = $('html')[0].scrollWidth - $('html')[0].clientWidth;
  
  // Divide by 2 to get half
  var top = maxScrollLeft / 2;
  
  // If the value is bigger than half show the button, otherwise hide it
  if (value > top){
    $('#button').show();
  }
  else {
    $('#button').hide();
  }
});

// GO BACK TO START
$ ('#button').on('click', function(){
  $('html').scrollLeft(0);
});
```

```css
html {
  width: 6000px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: relative;
} 
 
#button {
   position: fixed;
   color: red;
   left: 10px;
   top: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button">GO BACK</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I visible the button if the user scrolls from the centre and hide it otherwise?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. What is the trigger? When does the button show and when does it hide?

Comment: imaging a jump to the top button. If a user scrolls for example 50 unit down the page then a button appears on the right bottom corner  (for example) of the page and when  click on it, the user scrolls to the top of the page and the button disappears. Now we want to implement it horizontally. If the scroll moves from the center by 50 units (for example) then the button appears and when center the page disappears.

Comment: Oh okay I understood that totally different :p I will edit